# What is the best way to detect the color of circles detected using cv2.HoughCircles?

Tags: python, opencv

I am fairly new to image processing and opencv. I need to detect the colors of some balls. I started by detecting these balls using `cv2.HoughCircles` but after that i am stuck.

Most answers online suggest using contours and matching them with color ranges or calculating the distance to the closest color. But i couldn't find a way to transform the output of `cv2.HoughCircles` to contours (i am not sure if this is possible)

```
 while reader.isOpened():
        ret, frame = reader.getCapture()
        if ret:
            workingFrame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
           
            copy = frame.copy()
            grayMask = cv2.cvtColor(copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
            circlesArr = cv2.HoughCircles(grayMask, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.3, 20, param1=40, param2=30, minRadius=5, maxRadius=20)

            if circlesArr is not None:
                for circle in circlesArr[0, :]:
                    # detect colors             
                    cv2.circle(frame, (circle[0], circle[1]), circle[2], GREEN, 1)
                    cv2.circle(frame, (circle[0], circle[1]), 2, GREEN, 2)

            cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        else:
            break

        if quitKeyPressed():
            break
```

[image: Image to be processed]

Comment: @nathancy thank you for your help. I tried to implement this idea however the problem is that, as you can see from the picture, the balls can have different colors. When i apply the mask using one color the result is very rarely detected as a circle. 

Is there a way to see if a certain pixel ( say the center of a circle ) is inside the area marked by a certain color mask ?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting for the red and blue marble at bottom left of image?

Comment: I would say blue is more dominant so blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the dominant color for each circle using the following steps:
First i detected the circles with `cv2.HoughCircles`:

```
def detectCirclesWithDp(frame, dp=1):
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(frame, 25)
    grayMask = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # cannyMask = cv2.Canny(grayMask, 50, 240)
    return cv2.HoughCircles(grayMask, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, 40, param1=10, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=70)
```

Then for each circle i selected a roi around it:

```
def getROI(frame, x, y, r):
    return frame[int(y-r/2):int(y+r/2), int(x-r/2):int(x+r/2)]
```

After that i calculate the most dominant color in the region using kmeans and color masks:

```
COLOR_NAMES = [RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, CYAN, BLUE, PURPLE, RED_2]

COLOR_RANGES_HSV = {
    "red": [(0, 50, 10), (10, 255, 255)],
    "orange": [(10, 50, 10), (25, 255, 255)],
    "yellow": [(25, 50, 10), (35, 255, 255)],
    "green": [(35, 50, 10), (80, 255, 255)],
    "cyan": [(80, 50, 10), (100, 255, 255)],
    "blue": [(100, 50, 10), (130, 255, 255)],
    "purple": [(130, 50, 10), (170, 255, 255)],
    "red ": [(170, 50, 10), (180, 255, 255)]
}

def getMask(frame, color):
    blurredFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 0)
    hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(blurredFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    colorRange = COLOR_RANGES_HSV[color]
    lower = np.array(colorRange[0])
    upper = np.array(colorRange[1])

    colorMask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, lower, upper)
    colorMask = cv2.bitwise_and(blurredFrame, blurredFrame, mask=colorMask)

    return colorMask

def getDominantColor(roi):
    roi = np.float32(roi)

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    K = 4
    ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(roi, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    center = np.uint8(center)
    res = center[label.flatten()]
    res2 = res.reshape(roi.shape)

    pixelsPerColor = []
    for color in COLOR_NAMES:
        mask = getMask(res2, color)
        greyMask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        count = cv2.countNonZero(greyMask)
        pixelsPerColor.append(count)

    return COLOR_NAMES[pixelsPerColor.index(max(pixelsPerColor))]
```

Everything put together:

```
def detect():
    circles = detector.detectCirclesWithDp(imgCopy)
    if circles is not None:
        for circle in circles[0, :]:
            if imageUtils.inFrame(img, circle[0], circle[1]):
                roi = imageUtils.getROI(imgCopy, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2])
                color = colorlabeler.getDominantColor(roi)
                cv2.circle(img, (circle[0], circle[1]), circle[2], colorlabeler.COLORS_RGB["green"], 1)
                cv2.circle(img, (circle[0], circle[1]), 2, colorlabeler.COLORS_RGB["green"], 2)
                cv2.putText(img, color, (int(circle[0] + 40), int(circle[1] + 20)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                               colorlabeler.COLORS_RGB["green"])

    while True:
        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And finally the result:

[image]